# extract contents of .pkg file in java

Tags: java

I have been trying to unpack a .pkg file, which contains two folders and a .json file, into a directory using Java. I have used the apache.commons.compress library in the past, but unable to use it for the .pkg file. Please let me know how i can do this.

Many thanks

Comment: I suggest removing the line "Please let me know if it is possible to do so using a library", because it tells us that you're trying to get library recommendations which could lead to this question being closed before anyone can answer.

Comment: How do you know what's in the .pkg? Did you already unpack it with a regular tool? (hint: just because you have java, that does not make java the tool you should be using. Make java _call_ the tool for unpacking pkg files instead)

Comment: i had a jbz which contains a folder, which contains two .pkg files. I am searching for some such tools i can use with java. Thanks

Comment: Then first search for a tool that can unpack .pkg files, Google and friends will be more than happy to help you do that, and then just make java exec that using [the Runtime object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html). or start looking for java bindings to the tools you now know exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to unpack. The .pkg file was actually a .cpio payload file with some header and tail bytes.